# ¿Por qué no puedo crear la tabla en el sqlfiddle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlfiddle

Al tratar de crear una base de datos en el sitio [sqlfiddle](/questions/tagged/sqlfiddle) me marca el error:

> ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace FIDDLEDATA

Estoy casi seguro de que no es un error en mi consulta, porque ya borré los inserts y dejé únicamente las dos sentencias para crear las tablas y me marca el mismo error.

[image: Imágen del Error]

Comment: En este momento también me marca el mismo error, probablemente tienen un problema con su almacenamiento.

Comment: olvidé decir que googlee y me salen como dos resultados a ese error pero la verdad no los entiendo :P Espero alguien me ayude a entender que tipo de error es este para aprender algo el día de hoy :D

Comment: Esta pregunta es más un issue que debe ser enviado al equipo de SQL Fiddle que una pregunta de StackOverflow

Comment: Primero quise preguntar a los expertos para asegurarme que no fuera un problema mío ;)

Comment: A mi me parece que es una pregunta válida. SQL Fiddle es una herramienta usada en el desarrollo, además de no ser inmediato el porque hay un error en la página en lugar de ser un error de codificación

Comment: Y por ello sqlfiddle es una etiqueta totalmente válida en stackoverflow @CarlosMuñoz, además de que en la versión en inglés se encuentran errores que no son de codificación( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996746/sqlfiddle-oracle-11g-unable-to-create-schema ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La organización de las estructuras de almacenamiento en Oracle es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**De arriba hacia abajo van de mayor a menor tamaño.**

Físicamente los datos son almacenados en un Data File, estos son los archivos que encuentras en el sistema operativo. Ahora bien, de manera lógica los datos se organizan en `tablespaces` que son contenedores de objetos y pueden estar repartidos en muchos `data files`.

Los segments representan cualquier objeto que necesite almacenamiento, el caso más común es una tabla, pero también podrían ser índices. Un `segment` solo puede pertenecer a un `tablespace`, pero un `tablespace` se puede repartir en varios `data files`, por lo tanto el tamaño de una tabla no está limitado por el sistema operativo en ninguna forma.

Los bloques Oracle son las unidades en las que se miden las operaciones de Entrada/Salida y su tamaño es configurable al crear la base de datos. Sin embargo trabajar solo a nivel de bloques sería muy tardado, por ello se agrupan en `extents`, que son un conjunto de bloques numerados, que a su vez componen a los `segments`.

Finalmente los bloques de sistema operativo tienen un tamaño específico para cada sistema de archivos (default 512 B en NTFS, 1 KB en ext3), y son la unidad mínima en la que se componen los `data files` y los bloques Oracle.

Con esta explicación en mente, el error que se produjo en SQLFiddle (ORA-01658) puede indicar que el `tablespace FIDDLEDATA` está lleno, y por lo tanto no se pueden crear `extents` para las tablas de tu consulta. Si tu fueras el DBA podrías ejecutar una operación para aumentar el tamaño del `data file`, o añadir un nuevo `data file` al `tablespace`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya le envié un correo al administrador del sitio. Espero se resuelva pronto el inconveniente para poder seguir aprendiendo mis consultas recursivas :D