# Alternativa a SQLFiddle

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, sqlfiddle

La página http://sqlfiddle.com actualmente no permite crear tablas, alguién conoce alguna alternativa a esta página?

El issue ya se reporto al equipo desarrollador de sqlfiddle, pero aún no se soluciona, por esa razón ahora pregunto por alternativa a SQLFiddle.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencia: [¿Por qué no puedo crear la tabla en el sqlfiddle?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1905/por-qu%C3%A9-no-puedo-crear-la-tabla-en-el-sqlfiddle) .

Comment: Parece que actualmente SQL Fiddle se ha quedado sin espacio para alamcenar mas datos, puedes checar esto aqui http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1905/por-qu%C3%A9-no-puedo-crear-la-tabla-en-el-sqlfiddle

Comment: Esta pregunta es más un issue que debe ser enviado al equipo de SQL Fiddle que una pregunta de StackOverflow

Comment: @JuanK me gustaria conocer otra paginas que similares a SQL Fiddle, pues ya se resporto el issue y aún no se soluciona.

Comment: Hay un par de proyectos del mismo estilo que a lo mejor te pueden ayudar. Tienen más o menos la misma funcionalidad, varían en los motores de búsqueda que soportan: https://alternativa1.com/aplicacion/sqlfiddle

Answer (score 4):

Si tu base de datos es Oracle puedes usar [Oracle Apex](https://apex.oracle.com), para empezar realiza los siguientes pasos

1. Selecciona Free Workspace
2. Selecciona Application Development
3. Llena los datos de registro
4. Te llegará un email de acceso a tu cuenta
5. Ingresa a SQL Workshops

Ahora puedes crear tablas, hacer consultas e incluso ejecutar scripts, todo en un ambiente web y con una razonable cantidad de espacio de almacenamiento para hacer pruebas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Enrique, ya cree mi esquema y puedo hacer lo que mencionas, excepto compartir mi esquema para solicitar o brindar ayuda al estilo SQLFiddle. :/